# Python program should still run even when system sleeps [Uuntu]

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, operating-system, sleep-mode

I'd like to keep my Python program running, even when my computer is sleeping. The python program should not stop even when the system sleeps.

I am using a Ubuntu.

My file is only on my computer, not online.

Please help me out to achieve this.

If you need more information, please leave a comment!

Comment: when system sleep then all programs can't run.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer -

No! you can't.

Details -

Sleep Mode is a power-saving state that is similar to pausing a DVD movie, all applications on the computer are suspended and there is no setting to change this. If you set the machine to sleep, then all programs are suspended. Sleep mode and hibernation both simply save the state your desktop is in (what programs are open, what files are accessed) in a file that is saved in RAM or on the hard drive respectively. But the computer is then put into a low power state.